# Object of abstract class type "Rectangle" is not allowed

Tags: c++, abstract-class, virtual-functions

```
//QuizShape.h
#ifndef QUIZSHAPE_H
#define QUIZHAPE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class QuizShape
{
protected:
    //outer and inner symbols, and label
    char border, inner;
    string quizLabel;
public:
    //base class constructor with defaults
    QuizShape(char out = '*', char in = '+', string name = "3x3 Square")
    {
        border = out;
        inner = in;
        quizLabel = name;
        cout << "base class constructor, values set" << endl << endl;
    };

    //getters
    char getBorder() const
    { return border; }
    char getInner() const
    { return inner; }
    string getQuizLabel() const
    { return quizLabel; }

    //virtual functions to be defined later
    virtual void draw( ) = 0;
    virtual int getArea( ) = 0;
    virtual int getPerimeter( ) = 0;

};


class Rectangle : public QuizShape
{
protected:
    //height and with of a rectangle to be drawn
    int height, width;
public:
    //derived class constructor
    Rectangle(char out, char in, string name,
                int h = 3, int w = 3):QuizShape(out, in, name)
    {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        cout << "derived class constructor, values set" << endl << endl;
    }

    //getters
    int getHeight() const
    { return height; }
    int getWidth() const
    { return width; }

    //*********************************************
    virtual void draw(const Rectangle &rect1)
    {
        cout << "draw func" << endl;
        cout << rect1.height << endl;
        cout << rect1.getWidth() << endl;
        cout << rect1.getQuizLabel() << endl;
    }

    virtual int getArea(const Rectangle &rect2)
    {
        cout << "area func" << endl;
        cout << rect2.getInner() << endl;
        cout << rect2.getBorder() << endl;
    }

    virtual int getPerimeter(const Rectangle &rect3)
    {
        cout << "perim func" << endl;
        cout << rect3.height << endl;
        cout << rect3.getWidth() << endl;
        cout << rect3.getQuizLabel() << endl;   
    }
    //************************************************
};



#endif
```

These are the class types so far.

```
//QuizShape.cpp
#include "QuizShape.h"
```

This currently does nothing but bridge the files.

```
//pass7.cpp
#include "QuizShape.cpp"

int main()
{
    Rectangle r1('+', '-', "lol", 4, 5);

    cout << r1.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << r1.getWidth() << endl;
    cout << r1.getInner() << endl;
    cout << r1.getBorder() << endl;
    cout << r1.getQuizLabel() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The code will not compile due to the fact that Rectangle is supposedly an abstract class, and when hovering over the declaration of `r1` in `main`, I receive the error

> "Object of abstract class type "Rectangle" is not allowed".

I have checked other answers on this site and others and have not come across something that solves the problem.

**NOTE: I understand that the statements for virtual functions ending in =0; cause the class to become an abstract one. QuizShape SHOULD be abstract. I have defined the virtual functions in Rectangle and yet it remains an abstract class.**

How can I modify the virtual functions Rectangle class so that Rectangle is no longer abstract?

Comment: Those are shadowing. I believe there are warnings for that.

Comment: Your `getArea`,`getArea`, `getPerimeter` have different function signature with functions declared in `QuizShape`

Answer (score 2):

Your methods int the abstract class `QuizShape` are:

```
virtual void draw( ) = 0;
virtual int getArea( ) = 0;
virtual int getPerimeter( ) = 0;
```

but in `Rectangle` they take `const Rectangle &rect1` as parameter so you shadowing the methods and not overriding the abstract one at all. You need to have methods in `Rectangle` with the same signature as the ones in the abstract base class.

Comment: Of course, something so obvious i would never see it. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

The overridden methods must have the exact same signature, in the derived class you have given them arguments.